# jQuery AJAX call to Slim Framework

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, slim

I am trying to use Slim in my project and I am having trouble getting the AJAX call set up correctly:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/api/addresses/",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {QID: QID, departmentID: departmentID}
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert(err.statusText);
        },
        success: function(data) {

        ...
```

My Slim File looks like so:

```
require_once('Slim3.php');

function loadEndpoint()
{
    global $app;

    //fetch
    $app->post('/addresses', function($request, $response, $args){
        $objDB = new DB;
        $json = $objDB
            -> setStoredProc("canvas_fetch_module_department_addresses")
            -> setParam("QID", $args['QID'])
            -> setParam("departmentID", $args['departmentID'])
            -> execStoredProc()
            -> parseXML();
        return $response->write($xml);
    });
}
```

I don't even see the AJAX call being made in my console so I assume that is where the problem is. Anything noticeable with the setup?

Comment: What does `console` has to say on this?

Comment: The AJAX call returns "Fatal error: Call to undefined function loadEndpoint()". Seems like its a Slim issue but not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced same problem using AJAX and SLIM:

**Remove '/' from calling URL "/api/addresses"**

If there is no error in API I hope this will fix your issue?

Read this for more detail: http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/problems/7071-optional-route-parameters-force-either-or-no-in-urls